# SQL Query Date time Suggestion

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a SQL which gets data until yesterday by using where clause as
"
Where tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1
"
The db is defined as such that when I want to get todays data, I will have use 0 and likewise for yesterdays data, I can use -1 and for day before -2.

My query works fine except on monday. As per the query it gives me data of Sunday which I don't want. Instead I need data from last monday to friday all together but when its Tuesday I only need data for previous day which in this case should be Monday.

How do I put this condition in the where clause.

Thanks

tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1

Comment: Note that [sql] is general / standard SQL but answers to this question are likely database-specific; also [teradata-sql-assistant] is a client. Please tag the specific database being used such as [sql-server], [oracle], etc. for better answers.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a column which has the current weekday or the current date, you can use `OR` to take care of these two situations. For example:

```
WHERE (
    (day = 1 AND tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" IN (-3,-4,-5,-6,-7)) OR
    (day > 1 AND tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1)
)
```

Here I am assuming you have a column `day` which indicates the current day of the week. If you do not, but you have a column `date` which indicates the current date, replace `day` above with `DATEPART('weekday',date)`.

Comment: For SQL Server, DATEPART values depend on locale DATEFIRST settings. For Teradata, better to use td_day_of_week or DayOfWeek which always return 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc.

Comment: Thanks Janis, This is really helpful.

One last question: How do i extract day info from current_date. 
Eg. Today is 2/6/2024 and I want to have TUE as the output

Thanks

Comment: @Virendra if you want the full name of the day (like `Tuesday`), you can use `DATENAME(weekday,current_date)`, and if you want just the first three letters capitalized, you can use `UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(wd,current_date),1,3))`. The functions may be different for your specific database, but the function names are probably something similar to this (for example, in Redshift it would be `TO_CHAR(current_date, 'Day')` instead of the `DATENAME` function).